# How to make two separate curves move together

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves

I'm looking to make a cable with a semi transparent outer sheath, and need the able to move and curve the cable. In order to have the sheath move with it, I'm trying to move a parent curve, the child curve being inside of the parent, and have the child move as the parent would. Is there any way to do this or do I have to manually copy every movement of the curve with the handles onto both curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the *Hook* modifier you can parent the vertices of 2 separate curves to the same empties or bones.

If you want to parent a curve vertex to a bone:

- Disable the *Lock Object Mode* option:

[image]

- Select the bone in *Pose* mode, shift select the curve, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertex, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Object Bone*:

[image]

- It has automatically created a Hook modifier for the curve:

[image]

Move the bone, it will move the vertex, the advantage compared to a hook to empty is that you can always come back to the bone rest pose:

[image]

- To hook to an empty you just need to select the curve vertex and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object*, it will automatically create a new empty:

[image]

Now you can hook the vertices of the other curve to the same bones or empties.